# How to close the pop-up appearing during video playback?

Tags: ios, swift, video-streaming, html5-video, xcode7

I don't know how to close the popup during video playback. 
I have referred a number of websites, but couldn't find the solution.
This is my first app.Please help me out.

Comment: when you want to close popup?

Comment: I want to close after a very few seconds

Answer (score 1):

You can close popup after your time using following line. Hope this answer help you

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
```

Comment: @New-Leaner in which part should I add this line?

Comment: First you set timer and after ending counter write this line

Comment: @New-Leaner how to set timer programmatically